# Some menu item visible only for user browsing from outside India

Tags: routes, location

How to make some **menu item** of **main-menu** **visible** only for user browsing from **outside India**.
Pls suggest any solution

Comment: I don't think that this question is too broad. The question is very clear. The OP should set the `access callback` in `hook_menu()` or `hook_menu_alter()` and check the user's IP in his custom access callback. I would write an answer if the question was not closed.

Comment: Pls reply on 2alokjha@gmail.com will very thankfull